I seem unable to get rid of the "Personalize your profile" popup
I have clicked "Finish setup", entered a tag I am interested in, clicked "Done", but the popup keeps popping up, and when I click "Finish setup" again, the tag I chose is gone.
Also, there are scrollbars around that part of the header:

Here is what I enter and submit:

The tag ("r") is gone, when I click "Finish set up" the next time, and I cannot find the tag saved anywhere to my profile (e.g. under "Watched tags") .
Happens in both Firefox 127.0 and Safari 17.5 under macOS 14.5.

I reported this at https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/400779/1373352 . It happens on multiple SE sites and with different browsers.

Thanks, @DanielT. If you want, you can link to this post or add the information about my browsers to your post.
